# Submit a request with KendoUI that requires authentication

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, basic-authentication, http-authentication

I'm attempting to load some data into KendoUI, but I can't properly get data using a DataSource because the website that will provide it requires basic authentication. Obviously, when I try with no authentication it just gives me a 401 error. I also get a 401 error when I try using authentication as described [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-set-authorization-header-for-transport-read). Here's my sample code:

```
   var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
       transport: {
           read: {
               url: "http://localhost:8080/odata/SDA/TEIID_TEST",
               beforeSend: function(req){
                  req.setRequestHeader("Authorization",'Basic dXNlcjp1c2Vy');
               }
           }
       }
    });
   dataSource.read();
```

(Note: the string "dXNlcjp1c2Vy" translates to "user:user", which is my user/login for now.) When I try running the code, it shows me this in Tamper Data for Firefox:
[image: Tamper data result]

Note that a query when I visit the TEIID_TEST page directly and manually enter a username and password, it shows this:
[image]

It seems I'm not properly setting the Authorization header value, but I'm not sure how. Thoughts?

Comment: What type of authentication is required for this site?

Comment: Are you using a web app to request the data;.

Comment: @lrb It just need basic authentication, and I'm requesting data from the web browser as shown in the code from a Teiid server.